# Keep getting this message: * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found whe

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00923

I entered this:

```
SELECT COST TO_CHAR(COALESCE (COST, 0), '$99,990.99') 
  FROM COURSE;
SELECT COST TO_CHAR(NVL(cost, 0), '$99,990.99') COST
  FROM COURSE;
```

Then I get this message:

```
SELECT COST TO_CHAR(COALESCE (COST, 0), '$99,990.99')
                   *
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected 
SELECT  COST TO_CHAR(NVL(cost, 0), '$99,990.99') COST
                    *
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

I am trying to get the costs of the courses, while in a specific format:

```
COST
-------------
 $0.00
 $1,000.00
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The queries should be like this:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(COALESCE (COST, 0), '$99,990.99') FROM COURSE;
SELECT  TO_CHAR(NVL(cost, 0), '$99,990.99')  FROM COURSE;
```

There were too much `COST` keyword in your SELECT statement.

If you want to keep the `COST` column while formatting it, add the commas like this:

```
SELECT COST, TO_CHAR(COALESCE (COST, 0), '$99,990.99') COST_FORMATTED FROM COURSE;
SELECT COST, TO_CHAR(NVL(cost, 0), '$99,990.99') COST_FORMATTED FROM COURSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You a lacking a comma after the first `COST`:

```
SELECT COST, TO_CHAR(COALESCE (COST, 0), '$99,990.99') FROM COURSE; 
SELECT COST, TO_CHAR(NVL(cost, 0), '$99,990.99') FROM COURSE;
```

And it doesn't make sense to name the second column `COST` if you select cost to begin with.